# BASH : mount usb drive on a non root user does not give rights to write to the drive

Tags: bash, permissions, usb, mount

I am using the mount command in a script to mount a usb drive in Bash.  I have turned off haldameon, and autofs so that the drive will not automount.

Everything works in Root and also if you run it in root then switch to the non-root account.  However when coming from shutdown into the non-root account and then running the script the drive will mount but not allow write commands.

Here is some pseudo code:

turn off autofs, haldaemon
insert drives manually into the computer 
run the mount
try to write using the directory /mnt/

error permissions

Here is the turn off automount code.

```
#stop automounter
/etc/init.d/autofs stop 
#stop hal daemon, this is the hardware abstraction layer
/etc/init.d/haldaemon stop
```

Here is the mount code:

```
    #WHITE---------------------------------------

    if grep -qs '/mnt/WHITE' /proc/mounts; then 
        echo "WHITE Mounted re-mounting Unnecessary" 
    else
        #check if the directories are already there and remove if necessary
        if [ -d "/mnt/WHITE" ] ; then
            rmdir "/mnt/WHITE"
        fi

        #create directory and mount by label
        mkdir -p /mnt/WHITE
        mount -L WHITE /mnt/WHITE

        #check if the WHITE USB Drive is mounted to the correct directory
        if [ -d "/mnt/WHITE" ] ; then 
            #check if USB is mounted by location
            if grep -qs '/mnt/WHITE' /proc/mounts; then 
                echo "WHITE Mounted"
            else
                echo $errorstatus_white_mount
                exit 1
            fi
        else
            echo $errorstatus_white_mount
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
```

Here is the copy code that has the error:

```
echo "Copying Test Files to Drives"
#copy 
cp $copyfile "/mnt/WHITE"
cp $copyfile "/mnt/GREEN"
cp $copyfile "/mnt/RED"
sync
sleep 2
```

Also the commands for mount, /etc/init.d/autofs stop, /etc/init.d/haldaemon stop are in the sudoers file.

Thanks for the help with this permission mystery.

Comment: What does the fstab entry for /mnt/WHITE look like?

Comment: owner: root, Create & Delete; group: root, Access Files; others: Access Files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that you're not passing some parameters in the mount/fstab. You could try explicitly passing options in your script like so;

```
mount -L WHITE /mnt/WHITE -o rw
```

which specifically gives it read/write permissions, or

```
mount -L WHITE /mnt/WHITE -o rw,uid=test,gid=test
```

which mounts with read/writes as well as making the device accessible for user:group `test`

Comment: This worked.  I also then used a chown on them to be sure that I can access the /mnt/<label> directory thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions on the mnt drivers

```
ls -l
```

they are probably owned by root hence why you cant write to them.

Might need to chown them:

```
chown domain:user /mnt/{WHITE|GREEN|RED}
```

Comment: I used this in conjunction with above, however it did not work on its own.